# Corona sdk linking sprite sheets

Tags: sdk, instance, sprite, sequence, coronasdk

In Corona sdk, is there a way to start a new sprite sheet when the first one ends? I would like to be able to  use several sprite sheets instances in sequence. Each sprite sheet would start at the x and y position of the one that ended. As an example, I have one instance that plays several loops of a walk cycle. When that one ends, I want to start another one of the same game character falling down, or something else. To do this in one sprite instance would probably consume too many resources in the user device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not having a few instances. First is visible and other instances are invisible.
Then when thirst one ends you will position the second sprite sheet instance at .x and .y coordinates of first sprite sheet instance. Then hide the first sprite sheet and show the second sprite sheet + play it.

Comment: That would probably work. My only concern is the sprite sheets are fairly large, and more instances might consume all the device resources. As it is right now, my only option may be to run the instance, remove it, then start another.